# Settings api sanatize callback not being triggered

Tags: settings-api, validation, sanitization

I'm creating a custom settings page for a custom theme however the callbacks for sanatizing the data in the fields are not being called (I put in xdebug breakpoints in them to check).

```
/**
*------------------------- Admin Page Titles -------------------------
*/

function header_options_text() {
    echo '<p>These options affect the Header content.</p>';
}

/**
*------------------------- Header Options -------------------------
*/

function phone_number_input() {
    $option = get_option('header_phone');
    echo '<input id="header_phone" name="header_phone" size="40" type="text" value="'.$option.'"> </input>';
}
function header_logo_input() {
    $option = get_option('header_logo');
    echo '<input id="header_logo" name="header_logo" size="40" type="text" value="'.$option.'"> </input>';
}

/**
*------------------------- Header Validation Options -------------------------
*/

function header_phone_validate($input) {
    $new_input=trim($input);
    if(get_option( 'header_phone' ) === $new_input || !preg_match('/^[\+\d\(\)\- ]*$/', $new_input))
        $new_input=get_option( 'header_phone' );
    return $new_input;
}
function header_logo_validate($input) {
    $new_input=esc_url_raw(trim($input));
    if(get_option( 'header_logo' ) === $new_input && !filter_var($new_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        $new_input=get_option( 'header_logo' );
    return $input;
}

/**
 *------------------------- Actually create the pages and add to menu -------------------------
 */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ec1_admin', 10, 0 );
function ec1_admin() {
    add_menu_page( 'EC1 Theme Options', 'EC1 Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'ec1-theme-options', 'ec1_theme_options_page' );
}

function ec1_theme_options_page() {
    ?>
    <div>
        <h2>EC1 Theme Options</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php settings_fields('header-options'); ?>
            <?php settings_fields('header-logo-options'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'ec1-theme-options' ); ?>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}


add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init');
function plugin_admin_init(){
    register_setting( 'header-options', 'header_phone', 'header_phone_validate' );
    register_setting( 'header-logo-options', 'header_logo', 'header_logo_validate' );
    add_settings_section('header-options-pane', 'Header Options', 'header_options_text', 'ec1-theme-options');
    add_settings_field('header_phone', 'Phone Number', 'phone_number_input', 'ec1-theme-options', 'header-options-pane');
    add_settings_field('header_logo', 'Header Logo', 'header_logo_input', 'ec1-theme-options', 'header-options-pane');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have typos in your code :

in the function called `header_logo_validate()` it should be :

```
return $new_input;
```

EDIT:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ec1_admin', 10, 0 );
```

args are useless just write `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ec1_admin');`

EDIT 2 :

This is not a correct way to add several fields. You should put this into arrays or in one callback.

Maybe you need to globalize $settings (write `global $settings;`) to make `esc_url()` work in this context, [see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60904/esc-url-not-working-within-add-settings-field-callback)

Comment: While this is true, a breakpoint on     $new_input=esc_url_raw(trim($input)); is not triggering with xdebug, showing the function isn't even running!

Comment: The other validation does not have this typo and has the same issue.

Comment: why do you use `esc_url_raw()` and not `esc_url()`? `esc_url_raw` does not replace entities for display

Comment: I wasn't sure if I wanted to replace entities, but still, it's not even entering the function, breakpoints halt execution at the beginning of the line of code, not the end.

Comment: I've edited my answer hoep this helps. I think you should rebuild your code